# (postgres) Join tables usando um valor dentro de uma coluna JSONB

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Supondo que eu tenha duas tabelas com essas informações:

| id | sms_brocker_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 39c3 |
| 2 | 4e72 |
| 3 | a3ec |

| id | dados |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"status": {"id": 5, "success": true}, "messageId": "39c3" } |
| 2 | {"status": {"id": 3, "success": true}, "messageId": "12db" } |
| 3 | {"status": {"id": 1, "success": true}, "messageId": "7822" } |

Como eu faria para selecionar todas as colunas da primeira tabela em que o valor de sms_brocker_id seja igual ao valor de messageId dentro da coluna dados e também retornar o id de status?

Comment: Vê se te ajuda: https://dbfiddle.uk/He0H2hCa